# How do I get cucumber and databasecleaner to leave my seed data in my rails test db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have several database tables that have data that is for display purposes only, it never changes.  It takes a long time to load all the seed data.  I am using cucumber which seems to use the database_cleaner gem before each scenario to truncate all the tables in the test db. Is there a way to tell database_cleaner or cucumber to leave a few tables alone or am i stuck with loading my seed data before every scenario?
I am running 
rails 2.3.8
cucumber 0.10.0
cucumber-rails 0.3.2
database_cleaner 0.50.0
Any help is much appreciated.
Tom

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are using `ActiveRecord` or `DataMapper` you should be able to use the `:transaction` strategy instead of `:truncation`.

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
```

Or as @traday points out, you can use an exclusion list with truncation.

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, {:except => %w[widgets]}
```

The [DatabaseCleaner docs](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) are worth reading. Look in `features/support/env.rb` for where this is typically set up with Cucumber.

Comment: jdl - thanks again.  I looked at it again and now understand the :transaction strategy as well. Cheers.